# Draw a pandas plot like "Americans are more confident than Britons that they could beat any animal in a fight" by YouGov

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'd like to plot a graph like this [tweet](https://twitter.com/YouGov/status/1395680578771591168?s=20&t=iAMMEilt8XMqcTogAc2o4w):
[image: Plot showing delta between average US & Briton survey responses for confidence in beating an animal in a fight]

Does anyone know how to create a graph like this in matplotlib/seaborn?

I tried making a similar graph using matplotlib, but am having difficulties.

Comment: It's a scatter plot with horizontal lines between the two groups, and annotations.

Comment: To be answerable, a StackOverflow question is expected to have reproducible test data and your best-effort attempt for a minimal code example.